# Use a nonlicensed account to access a sharepoint folder?

Tags: office-365, licensing, credentials

I am considering using SharePoint to backup some important files (not a lot of data).  However, I don't want to hard-code my credentials into our backup scripts.  I also don't want to pay 10 bucks a month and waste Office licenses.  Is it possible to create an unlicensed user and use that account to access a specific share?

Comment: I didn't think you needed a license to access a site. You just need an account on the companies domain. At the least, this is how our service accounts work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SharePoint Online, unfortunately no. Even "service" accounts must have some form of licensing associated with them to access SharePoint. This isn't *enforced* (except for Project Online sites) but if you're audited, you may be required to license the account.

Backup products that are aware of SharePoint online will typically use App-Only permissions instead, which allows the application to interact with the content without requiring any form of license.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create an unlicensed "service" account for automated operations against SharePoint, and in fact, this is a best practice.

Another option would be app-only permission, where you can specify the exact permissions your app will need.

Answer (score 0):

Look into external sharing, or sharing with external users.

Ref:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview
[Turn external sharing on or off](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)

There is a lot of information on those links (too much to summarize her). I get the impression that you may need at least an enterprise tenant (i.e. any of the E plans) to do it.

Ref:
[SharePoint Online - External Sharing, licensing](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/SharePoint-Online-External-Sharing-licensing/td-p/137707)